# MongoDB Shutting down. Signal 15

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

Using MongoDB in a live server. Everyday in the morning, I find that mongod process is shutdown. The mongodb log is as follows:

```
2017-11-02T11:19:49.173+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2017-11-02T11:19:49.174+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-11-02T11:19:49.469+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:34826 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-11-02T11:20:20.112+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:34828 #2 (2 connections now open)
2017-11-02T11:27:34.728+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-11-02T11:27:34.728+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-11-02T11:27:34.728+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2017-11-02T11:27:34.728+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2017-11-02T11:27:34.728+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-11-02T11:27:34.728+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-11-02T11:27:34.728+0000 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2017-11-02T11:27:34.730+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2017-11-02T11:27:34.795+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-11-02T11:27:34.795+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2017-11-02T11:27:34.795+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:0
```

My mongodb configuration file is as follows:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Most of the solutions online are related to setting processManagement.fork to false, which I believe is it's default value.

Comment: What is the version you are using??? I mean mongo version

Comment: It is Version 3.4. It is there in tags.

Comment: any chance it is simply the server rebooting for some reason? A signal 15 is just an orderly shutdown request, the real question is what is sending the signal to your MongoDB process (if it was rebooting it would be the system itself). It's impossible to tell where the signal is coming from given the information here I'm afraid

Comment: Thank you for answer. I could not find any error both here and syslog that would suggest an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fork is false then mongo dies when shell (where you started mongo) die. Set fork to true